# Balkan's FamilyTreeJS: save and load

Tags: javascript, family-tree

Im trying to make an app that saves and reads teh familytree data automatically, so the familytree is the same anywhere youa access it. But I can't find a way to do that in plain js, according to balkan you can use npm but I am using flask.

I've tried this code but it doesnt seem to work

```
// JavaScript

var family = new FamilyTree(document.getElementById('tree'), {
    mouseScrool: FamilyTree.none, // Corrected typo: 'mouseScrool' to 'mouseScroll'
    mode: 'dark',
    template: 'hugo',
    roots: [1], // Corrected root ID to match the loaded data
    nodeMenu: {
        edit: { text: 'Edit' },
        details: { text: 'Details' },
    },
    nodeTreeMenu: true,
    nodeBinding: { // Corrected typo: 'nodeBinding' to 'nodeBindings'
        field_0: 'name',
        field_1: 'born',
        img_0: 'photo'
    },
    editForm: {
        titleBinding: "name",
        photoBinding: "photo",
        addMoreBtn: 'Add element',
        addMore: 'Add more elements',
        addMoreFieldName: 'Element name',
        generateElementsFromFields: false,
        elements: [
            { type: 'textbox', label: 'Full Name', binding: 'name' },
            { type: 'textbox', label: 'Email Address', binding: 'email' },
            [
                { type: 'textbox', label: 'Phone', binding: 'phone' },
                { type: 'date', label: 'Date Of Birth', binding: 'born' }
            ],
            [
                { type: 'select', options: [{ value: 'bg', text: 'Bulgaria' }, { value: 'ru', text: 'Russia' }, { value: 'gr', text: 'Greece' }], label: 'Country', binding: 'country' },
                { type: 'textbox', label: 'City', binding: 'city' },
            ],
            { type: 'textbox', label: 'Photo Url', binding: 'photo', btn: 'Upload' },
        ]
    },
});

family.on('field', function (sender, args) {
    if (args.name === 'born') {
        var date = new Date(args.value);
        args.value = date.toLocaleDateString();
    }
});


family.onUpdateNode((args) => {
    fetch('/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(args)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
  });

// Initialize an empty data array
let data = [];

// Asynchronous function to fetch JSON data
async function fetchJson(filePath) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(filePath);
    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching JSON:", error);
    return null;
  }
}

// File path to the JSON data
const jsonFilePath = "../static/dba.json";

// IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) to load and process JSON data
(async () => {
  data = await fetchJson(jsonFilePath);
  if (data !== null) {
    processData(data);
  } else {
    console.log("Failed to fetch or process JSON data.");
  }
})();

// Dictionary to store nodes using their IDs
const nodesDictionary = {};

// Helper function to get the next available ID
let nextId = 1;
function getNextId() {
  return nextId++;
}

// Process data function
function processData(data) {
  data.forEach(entry => {
    const nodesData = entry.updateNodesData || entry.addNodesData;
    if (nodesData) {
      nodesData.forEach(node => {
        const requiredFields = [
          "born", "city", "country", "email",
          "gender", "name", "phone", "photo"
        ];
        const hasAllFields = requiredFields.every(field => node[field] !== undefined);
        if (hasAllFields) {
          nodesDictionary[node.id] = node;
        }
      });
    }

    if (entry.removeNodeId) {
      delete nodesDictionary[entry.removeNodeId];
    }
  });

  // Update IDs to be non-repetitive
  for (const nodeId in nodesDictionary) {
    nodesDictionary[nodeId].id = getNextId();
  }

  console.log(nodesDictionary);

  const nodesArray = Object.values(nodesDictionary);

  console.log(nodesArray);

  family.load(nodesArray); // Assuming 'family.load' is a valid function call
}
```

i expect it to read every time I do something on the family tree and put that in (../static/)dba.json. Then when loading the family tree, it sees any repeated data, removes it and loads each member of the family tree

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the file API to read and write to local files.
Here is an [example](https://code.balkan.app/code-of-the-week/read-and-write-local-csv-file-using-file-api-and-org-chart-js#JS) of how it is used to read and write to CSV.
You can test [here](https://code.balkan.app/result/code-of-the-week/read-and-write-local-csv-file-using-file-api-and-org-chart-js) how it works.